# Finite union of epigraphs

Tags: functions, set-theory, convex-analysis

In page 6 of H.H. Bauschke and P.L. Combettes, *Convex Analysis and Monotone operator Theory in Hilbert spaces*, there is a small lemma saying the following: Let $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of functions from a real vector space $\mathcal{X}$ to $[-\infty, +\infty]$. If I is finite, then

$$\text{epi}(\min_{i \in I} f_i) = \bigcup_{i \in I} \text{epi} f_i.$$

By reading the proof, I understand why the equality holds, but I'm not able to see where the finiteness assumption is used. What am I missing? I will transcribe the proof for clarity.

\begin{align} (x,z) \in \text{epi}(\min_{i \in I} f_i) &\Leftrightarrow \min_{i \in I} f_i(x) \le z \\ 
&\Leftrightarrow \text{there is $i \in I$ such that } f_i(x) \le z \\
&\Leftrightarrow \text{there is $i \in I$ such that } (x,z)\in\text{epi} f_i \\
&\Leftrightarrow (x,z) \in \bigcup_{i \in I} \text{epi} f_i.
\end{align}

Comment: If I were infinite, you’d be taking the minimum of infinitely many real numbers; this min may not exist.

Comment: Of course... thank you very much.